How to Prompt for Credentials while accessing Network Shared Folder in a Domain environment
I'm currently tasked with maintaining our internal file server in an SMB company. Our setup includes a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine serving as both a file server and a domain controller. We have around 40 computers joined to the domain, with some users logging in with non-domain/local accounts on these domain-joined computers.
The issue arises when users with non-domain accounts attempt to access shared folders on the domain server. Instead of being prompted for credentials, they receive a "Windows cannot access <\share_name\shared_folder>" error.
Our requirement is for non-domain users to access shares on the domain file server for specific needs. How can I configure the domain file server to prompt users to enter domain credentials (username and password) whenever they attempt to access the shared drive?
Any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
